# How to add the cutome tag to the input field and then append all the tags vlaue to another input text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

1: The user want to add a [custom tag](http://codepen.io/curthusting/pen/FLhpE) to the first input text field if he does not find out the required tag during the autocomplete search.

2: He also need to copy all the tags value in the form of a text value from 1st input text to the 2nd input text field.

3: Currently I am using onkeyup to add the tags value from 1st input field to the 2nd input field.

Here is the [full code Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jyxZyw) regarded to my question.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#vidyagames').tokenInput([{
        id: 7,
        name: "Super Mario"
    }, {
        id: 11,
        name: "Battletoads"
    }, {
        id: 13,
        name: "Pong"
    }, {
        id: 17,
        name: "The Legend of Zelda"
    }, {
        id: 19,
        name: "Metroid"
    }, {
        id: 23,
        name: "Donkey Kong Country"
    }, {
        id: 29,
        name: "Super Smash Bros."
    }, {
        id: 32,
        name: "Star Fox"
    }, {
        id: 35,
        name: "Starcraft"
    }, {
        id: 37,
        name: "Pokemon"
    }, {
        id: 38,
        name: "Minecraft"
    }, {
        id: 41,
        name: "The Sims"
    }, {
        id: 43,
        name: "Final Fantasy"
    }, {
        id: 44,
        name: "Resident Evil"
    }, {
        id: 46,
        name: "Kingdom Hearts"
    }, {
        id: 47,
        name: "Tetris"
    }, {
        id: 48,
        name: "Grand Theft Auto"
    }, {
        id: 51,
        name: "World of Warcraft"
    }, {
        id: 53,
        name: "Metal Gear Solid"
    }, {
        id: 54,
        name: "Civilization"
    }, {
        id: 56,
        name: "Pac-Man"
    }, {
        id: 59,
        name: "Animal Crossing"
    }, {
        id: 62,
        name: "Spyro the Dragon"
    }, {
        id: 64,
        name: "Crash Bandicoot"
    }, {
        id: 65,
        name: "Sonic the Hedgehog"
    }, {
        id: 72,
        name: "Tomb Raider"
    }, {
        id: 77,
        name: "Mortal Kombat"
    }, {
        id: 81,
        name: "Space Invaders"
    }], {
        theme: "facebook",
        hintText: "Know of any cool games?",
        noResultsText: "Nothin' found.",
        searchingText: "Gaming...",
        preventDuplicates: true,
        onAdd: function(item){
          document.getElementById('n2').value = item.name;
        }
    });

});
```

```css
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Henny+Penny');
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
body {
    background: #e7e7e7 url('http://i.imgur.com/qoKmNN9.png');
    /* http://subtlepatterns.com/natural-paper/ */
    
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #444;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 65px;
}
br {
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
    display: block;
}
ol,
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
input,
textarea {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
strong,
b {
    font-weight: bold;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
img {
    border: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Henny Penny', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 3.35em;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    color: #616161;
}
p {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
/* page structure */

#wrapper {
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 35px 22px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#searchbar {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 0px;
}
/* custom settings */

.token-input-token-facebook p {
    font-size: 1.0em;
    color: #555;
}
.token-input-selected-token-facebook p {
    color: #fff;
}
/** tokeninputs **/
/* Example tokeninput style #1: Token vertical list*/

ul.token-input-list {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 1%;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    cursor: text;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    list-style-type: none;
    clear: left;
}
ul.token-input-list li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul.token-input-list li input {
    border: 0;
    width: 350px;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-appearance: caret;
}
li.token-input-token {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 1%;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    background-color: #d0efa0;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: default;
    display: block;
}
li.token-input-token p {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
li.token-input-token span {
    float: right;
    color: #777;
    cursor: pointer;
}
li.token-input-selected-token {
    background-color: #08844e;
    color: #fff;
}
li.token-input-selected-token span {
    color: #bbb;
}
div.token-input-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    z-index: 1;
}
div.token-input-dropdown p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #777;
}
div.token-input-dropdown ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div.token-input-dropdown ul li {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 3px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
div.token-input-dropdown ul li.token-input-dropdown-item {
    background-color: #fafafa;
}
div.token-input-dropdown ul li.token-input-dropdown-item2 {
    background-color: #fff;
}
div.token-input-dropdown ul li em {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
div.token-input-dropdown ul li.token-input-selected-dropdown-item {
    background-color: #d0efa0;
}
/** tokeninputs facebook **/
/* Example tokeninput style #2: Facebook style */

ul.token-input-list-facebook {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 1%;
    width: 550px;
    border: 1px solid #8496ba;
    cursor: text;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    min-height: 1px;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    list-style-type: none;
    clear: left;
}
ul.token-input-list-facebook li input {
    border: 0;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 2px 0;
    -webkit-appearance: caret;
}
li.token-input-token-facebook {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 1px 3px;
    background-color: #eff2f7;
    color: #000;
    cursor: default;
    border: 1px solid #ccd5e4;
    font-size: 11px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
li.token-input-token-facebook p {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
li.token-input-token-facebook span {
    color: #a6b3cf;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
li.token-input-selected-token-facebook {
    background-color: #5670a6;
    border: 1px solid #3b5998;
    color: #fff;
}
li.token-input-input-token-facebook {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
div.token-input-dropdown-facebook {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    z-index: 1;
}
div.token-input-dropdown-facebook p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #777;
}
div.token-input-dropdown-facebook ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div.token-input-dropdown-facebook ul li {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
div.token-input-dropdown-facebook ul li.token-input-dropdown-item-facebook {
    background-color: #fff;
}
div.token-input-dropdown-facebook ul li.token-input-dropdown-item2-facebook {
    background-color: #fff;
}
div.token-input-dropdown-facebook ul li em {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
div.token-input-dropdown-facebook ul li.token-input-selected-dropdown-item-facebook {
    background-color: #3b5998;
    color: #fff;
}​
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/src/jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>

<script>
    function sync() {
        var n1 = document.getElementById('vidyagames');
        var n2 = document.getElementById('n2');
        n2.value = n1.value;
    }
</script>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <h1>Dynamic Tag Input Suggestions</h1>
        <p>Start typing the name of a popular video game to get some helpful suggestions.</p>
        <div id="searchbar">
            1st input
            <input type="text" id="vidyagames" name="vidya" onkeyup="sync()">
            <br/>
            <br/> 2nd input
            <input id="n2" size="50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- @end #wrapper -->
</body>​
```

Answer (score 0):

First, [**here**](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) is a quick reference of Tokeninput.

I don't understand what meant by **step 1**. For **step 2** and **step 3**, you should set both: `onAdd` and `onDelete` to pass the array of currently selected tags (using `this.tokenInput("get")`) to sync which then will generate the value of the second input (no need to add any event listeners). like this:

```
onAdd: function(){
    sync(this.tokenInput("get"));
},
onDelete: function(){
    sync(this.tokenInput("get"));
}
```

And this:

```
function sync(items) {
    var value = items.reduce(function(s, item){
        // return s + '|' + item.name; // to separate the tags using | instead of a space
        return s + ' ' + item.name;
    }, '');

    // if you're already using jQuery why use document.getElementById
    $('#n2').val(value.slice(1)); // .slice to remove the first space
}
```

Working code:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#vidyagames').tokenInput([{
        id: 7,
        name: "Super Mario"
    }, {
        id: 11,
        name: "Battletoads"
    }, {
        id: 13,
        name: "Pong"
    }, {
        id: 17,
        name: "The Legend of Zelda"
    }, {
        id: 19,
        name: "Metroid"
    }, {
        id: 23,
        name: "Donkey Kong Country"
    }, {
        id: 29,
        name: "Super Smash Bros."
    }, {
        id: 32,
        name: "Star Fox"
    }, {
        id: 35,
        name: "Starcraft"
    }, {
        id: 37,
        name: "Pokemon"
    }, {
        id: 38,
        name: "Minecraft"
    }, {
        id: 41,
        name: "The Sims"
    }, {
        id: 43,
        name: "Final Fantasy"
    }, {
        id: 44,
        name: "Resident Evil"
    }, {
        id: 46,
        name: "Kingdom Hearts"
    }, {
        id: 47,
        name: "Tetris"
    }, {
        id: 48,
        name: "Grand Theft Auto"
    }, {
        id: 51,
        name: "World of Warcraft"
    }, {
        id: 53,
        name: "Metal Gear Solid"
    }, {
        id: 54,
        name: "Civilization"
    }, {
        id: 56,
        name: "Pac-Man"
    }, {
        id: 59,
        name: "Animal Crossing"
    }, {
        id: 62,
        name: "Spyro the Dragon"
    }, {
        id: 64,
        name: "Crash Bandicoot"
    }, {
        id: 65,
        name: "Sonic the Hedgehog"
    }, {
        id: 72,
        name: "Tomb Raider"
    }, {
        id: 77,
        name: "Mortal Kombat"
    }, {
        id: 81,
        name: "Space Invaders"
    }], {
        theme: "facebook",
        hintText: "Know of any cool games?",
        noResultsText: "Nothin' found.",
        searchingText: "Gaming...",
        preventDuplicates: true,
        onAdd: function(item){
           sync(this.tokenInput("get"));
        },
        onDelete: function(item){
           sync(this.tokenInput("get"));
        }
    }); 

});
```

```css
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Henny+Penny');
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
body {
    background: #e7e7e7 url('http://i.imgur.com/qoKmNN9.png');
    /* http://subtlepatterns.com/natural-paper/ */
    
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #444;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 65px;
}
br {
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
    display: block;
}
ol,
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
input,
textarea {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
strong,
b {
    font-weight: bold;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
img {
    border: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Henny Penny', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 3.35em;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    color: #616161;
}
p {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
/* page structure */

#wrapper {
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 35px 22px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#searchbar {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 0px;
}
/* custom settings */

.token-input-token-facebook p {
    font-size: 1.0em;
    color: #555;
}
.token-input-selected-token-facebook p {
    color: #fff;
}
/** tokeninputs **/
/* Example tokeninput style #1: Token vertical list*/

ul.token-input-list {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 1%;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    cursor: text;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    list-style-type: none;
    clear: left;
}
ul.token-input-list li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul.token-input-list li input {
    border: 0;
    width: 350px;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-appearance: caret;
}
li.token-input-token {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 1%;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    background-color: #d0efa0;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: default;
    display: block;
}
li.token-input-token p {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
li.token-input-token span {
    float: right;
    color: #777;
    cursor: pointer;
}
li.token-input-selected-token {
    background-color: #08844e;
    color: #fff;
}
li.token-input-selected-token span {
    color: #bbb;
}
div.token-input-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    z-index: 1;
}
div.token-input-dropdown p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #777;
}
div.token-input-dropdown ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div.token-input-dropdown ul li {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 3px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
div.token-input-dropdown ul li.token-input-dropdown-item {
    background-color: #fafafa;
}
div.token-input-dropdown ul li.token-input-dropdown-item2 {
    background-color: #fff;
}
div.token-input-dropdown ul li em {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
div.token-input-dropdown ul li.token-input-selected-dropdown-item {
    background-color: #d0efa0;
}
/** tokeninputs facebook **/
/* Example tokeninput style #2: Facebook style */

ul.token-input-list-facebook {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 1%;
    width: 550px;
    border: 1px solid #8496ba;
    cursor: text;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    min-height: 1px;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    list-style-type: none;
    clear: left;
}
ul.token-input-list-facebook li input {
    border: 0;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 2px 0;
    -webkit-appearance: caret;
}
li.token-input-token-facebook {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 1px 3px;
    background-color: #eff2f7;
    color: #000;
    cursor: default;
    border: 1px solid #ccd5e4;
    font-size: 11px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
li.token-input-token-facebook p {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
li.token-input-token-facebook span {
    color: #a6b3cf;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
li.token-input-selected-token-facebook {
    background-color: #5670a6;
    border: 1px solid #3b5998;
    color: #fff;
}
li.token-input-input-token-facebook {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
div.token-input-dropdown-facebook {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    z-index: 1;
}
div.token-input-dropdown-facebook p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #777;
}
div.token-input-dropdown-facebook ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div.token-input-dropdown-facebook ul li {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
div.token-input-dropdown-facebook ul li.token-input-dropdown-item-facebook {
    background-color: #fff;
}
div.token-input-dropdown-facebook ul li.token-input-dropdown-item2-facebook {
    background-color: #fff;
}
div.token-input-dropdown-facebook ul li em {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
div.token-input-dropdown-facebook ul li.token-input-selected-dropdown-item-facebook {
    background-color: #3b5998;
    color: #fff;
}​
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/src/jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>

<script>
    function sync(items) {
        var value = items.reduce(function(s, item){
            return s + ' ' + item.name;
        }, '');
      
        $('#n2').val(value.slice(1));
    }
</script>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <h1>Dynamic Tag Input Suggestions</h1>
        <p>Start typing the name of a popular video game to get some helpful suggestions.</p>
        <div id="searchbar">
            1st input
            <input type="text" id="vidyagames" name="vidya">
            <br/>
            <br/> 2nd input
            <input id="n2" size="50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- @end #wrapper -->
</body>​
```

Comment: in step 1: the user want to add a tag that have not been found in the search list. for example there are three tags in the autocomplete search list named with apple, banana and grapes.....when the user start to search a word "potato",  the result will be shown is "result not found". Then if he want to add the word "potato" as a tag he press the enter button and the potato must  become a tag in the input field.

Comment: when the user enter a word and then press the " , " then the word before the comma become a tag in 1st input text field

Comment: enter any name and then press enter button

Comment: @khanbhai Tokeninput doesn't have that functionality so I think you'll have to hardcode (or look for help). The example you provided on codepen uses a cutom one not Tokeninput.